# Error when spawning child process in node.js

Tags: node.js, spawn, execvp

I'm trying to get a little ffmpeg converter-service up and running, made pretty good progress so far. But when it comes to spawning the actual ffmpeg process for conversion, i'm hitting a brick wall.

```
// options.ffmpegopts is an array containing format-specific parameters
var args = [ '-y', '"' + options.targetfile + '"' ];
args = options.ffmpegopts.concat(args);

var ffmpegProc = spawn('ffmpeg ', args);
ffmpegProc.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log('stderr: ' + data);
});
```

When executing this code, i get the following console output:

```
stderr: execvp(): No such file or directory
```

I already checked different node versions (0.4.0, 0.4.2 and 0.5.0-pre) without any effect.

Another really strange behavior is the fact that i have to call spawn including a space (`'ffmpeg '` instead of just `'ffmpeg'`). If i omit this space, i get a different error (`stderr: "/path/to/my/movie.mpeg": no such file or directory`). When calling ffmpeg directly from the shell, the command sent to child_process.spawn() executes without any problems.

Any hints on that one? I already checked other projects who achieve the same (like [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) or [ffmpeg-node](https://github.com/xonecas/ffmpeg-node), but the enlightment didn't hit me...

### Update: strace() output

When running my application using `strace -fF -o strace.log node server.js`, i can grep the following process spawning calls:

```
execve("/usr/local/sbin/ffmpeg", ["ffmpeg", "-i", "\"/data/media_dev/test/ORG_mymovi"..., "-sameq", "-ab", "128k", "-ar", "44100", "-b", "512k", "-r", "25", "-s", "320x240", "-f", "flv", ...], [/* 20 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg", ["ffmpeg", "-i", "\"/data/media_dev/test/ORG_mymovi"..., "-sameq", "-ab", "128k", "-ar", "44100", "-b", "512k", "-r", "25", "-s", "320x240", "-f", "flv", ...], [/* 20 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/sbin/ffmpeg", ["ffmpeg", "-i", "\"/data/media_dev/test/ORG_mymovi"..., "-sameq", "-ab", "128k", "-ar", "44100", "-b", "512k", "-r", "25", "-s", "320x240", "-f", "flv", ...], [/* 20 vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
execve("/usr/bin/ffmpeg", ["ffmpeg", "-i", "\"/data/media_dev/test/ORG_mymovi"..., "-sameq", "-ab", "128k", "-ar", "44100", "-b", "512k", "-r", "25", "-s", "320x240", "-f", "flv", ...], [/* 20 vars */]) = 0
```

After seeing that strangely escaped double quotes on the path, i tried to call ffmpeg without the quotes...worked like a charm. But the problem remains, i need to be able to work with spaces in my paths.

Any suggestions?

### Update: Solution

Got it working with spaces, a simple `inputfile.replace(' ', '\ ')` was enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd wager money that the space at the end of `"ffmpeg "` is the cause of the current problem. A quick little C program will show that:

```
   #include <unistd.h>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
       execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
       perror(argv[0]);
   }
```

gives the following output:

```
$ ./execvp "ffmpeg"
FFmpeg version 0.6-4:0.6-2ubuntu6, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
...
$ ./execvp "ffmpeg "
./execvp: No such file or directory
$
```

I suggest removing the space again, and re-run under `strace(1) -fF`. Look for the command that is actually executed, and look to see if the error message about `/path/to/my/movie.mpeg` is coming from `ffmpeg` or from `node.js`.